# Convert folder name into key and inside folder images convert into array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.6

I am writing a script to convert the name of folder into the dictionary key and inside the images in each folder will be array values of each key. How can i achieve it?

Example
Angelina is folder name and inside her folder there are images belong to her. Then, this process remain same for all folder.

```
idendities = {
    "Angelina": ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img4.jpg", "img5.jpg", "img6.jpg", "img7.jpg", "img10.jpg", "img11.jpg"],
    "Scarlett": ["img8.jpg", "img9.jpg", "img47.jpg", "img48.jpg", "img49.jpg", "img50.jpg", "img51.jpg"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by something like this -

```
import os

key_value_map = {}

# Change root with your root directory name
root = 'test'

dir_list = os.listdir(root)

for dir in dir_list:
    files_list = os.listdir(os.path.join(root, dir))
    jpg_files = []

    for f in files_list:
        if f.endswith(".jpg"):
            jpg_files.append(f)

    key_value_map[dir] = jpg_files


print(key_value_map)
```

Assuming you have two directories namely Angelina & Scarlet in your working directory.

Comment: Actually, there 1000 folders of different celebrities and i cannot type the name of all folder. Is it any way to convert folder name into dictionary key?

Comment: You don't need to. The os.listdir() method will do that for you. Say you have a root folder named 'root' where you have all these celebrities folder. Now if the root folder is on your working directory, all you have to do is call os.listdir('root'). It should return you the list of celebrities directory. You can also use absolute path of the root folder if it is placed in somewhere else. So, if you follow this all you have to do is change one line in my code: dir_list = os.listdir('ROOT_DIR_PATH')
The rest should be same.

Comment: Please tell folder and images are present in this directory but it gives an error                              FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'TheodoreRoosevelt'

Comment: That's because, the child directories are not linked to the root path. I've mad a little change on the snippet, please try using it. Replace value of `root` variable with the directory name/path in which you have placed all  those celebrities directory. It should do the work. But remember it will only return jpg file names. If you need to access those files you should use `os.path.join()` relative to the root directory.

Comment: I need one more help please. I want that when one key value pair end then second key value pair starts from next line because now i am getting an error but condition is not good